# Why arguments aren't passed in wsdl method?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, onvif

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/search.wsdl

```
$this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, array(
  'trace' => true, 
  'exceptions' => true, 
  'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
  ),
  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
));
$this->client->__setLocation($service);
$params = array(
  'Scope' => array(
    'IncludedSources' => array('Token' => ''),
    'Extension'  => array(
      'CameraUuid' => $CameraUuid,
      'StartTime' => $StartTime,
      'StopTime' => $StopTime,
    ),
  ),
  'KeepAliveTime' => $KeepAlive
);
return $this->client->FindRecordings($params);
```

but in wireshark i see

```
<env:Body>
  <ns2:FindRecordings>
     <ns2:Scope>
        <ns1:IncludedSources>
           <ns1:Token />
        </ns1:IncludedSources>
        <ns1:Extension />
     </ns2:Scope>
     <ns2:KeepAliveTime>PT10S</ns2:KeepAliveTime>
  </ns2:FindRecordings>
```

why is it so? i have similar soap request with that wsdl http://192.168.0.14/onvif/wsdl/media.wsdl and then arguments are passed! please, help

Comment: I'm not sure but try set `'verify_peer' => false,` to `'verify_peer' => true,` because the aboe link uses https insted http as on local wsdl documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

Comment: no, it doesn't matter